# ThreeJS AdditiveBlending, ShaderMaterial, DepthTest problem

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm creating a scene with various objects and got inspired by this CodePen (https://codepen.io/gnauhca/pen/VzJXGG). In the example DepthTest is disabled on the ShaderMaterial but i need it be enabled because i would like to render Objects in front of the particle wave. But when i enable DepthTest i get a strange effect where it seems that only the left side of the material is rendered with AdditiveBlending and the right sight seems to loose blending/transparency. Also when i tilt the camera the effect becomes better or worse depending on the angle. See this jsfiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/hnmftqjp/ and a gif showcasing my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pSgi.jpg

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: waveVertexShader,
    fragmentShader: waveFragmentShader,

    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthTest: true,
    transparent: true
});
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `depthTest` enabled while maintaining transparent `AdditiveBlending` through your mesh, you need to set `depthWrite: false`:

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: waveVertexShader,
    fragmentShader: waveFragmentShader,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    transparent: true
});
```

[See here for details on `depthTest` and `depthWrite` attributes](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.depthTest)

Alternatively, if you want to render another Mesh after the first, so it's drawn "on top" of everything else, you can set the second object's render order like this: `mesh.renderOrder = 1`

[See here for docs on `Mesh.renderOrder`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder)

Comment: thank you so much! i messed with many attributes and even with the renderOrder but somehow it never worked. well, now it does :) thank you very much!